# Is the Atherton Raspberry known to hybridize with other Rubus species?

Tags: raspberries, hybrids

Is Rubus probus (the Atherton Raspberry) known to hybridize with other Rubus species? It sounds like it would be pretty awesome in breeding programs.

Comment: I had done about 1/2 an hour of research, and couldn't find anything. That doesn't mean no one has, so I can't really answer. Rubus species are usually easy to hybridize. You could do it at home

Comment: Hi Shule! I found this in the unanswered questions list and wondered if you want to self-answer. Did you do it? Did it work? Did you learn about it on some other site, that you could bring the information here. It's a good question, and the community would learn from it. If not, that's fine, I just thought I'd ask!

Comment: I don't know the answer. I don't have any Atherton Rasperry plants, and I don't think they're cold-hardy enough for my area (which was why I was interested in hybrids, if I remember). Sorry! Thanks for asking, though.

Comment: Looking at the number of chromosome, could be a good start.